# Android crop activity

Tags: android

I've using android CROP in my app and testing it using AVD - everything works well, but when I'm trying to test it on real device (sumsung galaxy s2) my app crashes after pressing button SAVE in CROP activity with "Unfortunately, Gallery has stopped". What is the reason?

LogCat:

> 06-26 17:31:53.443: E/MTPRx(13266): In
>   MtpReceiverandroid.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED
>
> 06-26 17:31:53.478: E/BrowserMediaChangingReceiver(11105):
>   BrowserMediaChangingReceiver : onReceive 06-26 17:31:53.478:
>   E/BrowserMediaChangingReceiver(11105): onReceive : mounted = %s false
>
> 06-26 17:31:53.478: E/BrowserMediaChangingReceiver(11105): onReceive :
>   false mounted = %s true
>
> 06-26 17:31:53.478: E/BrowserMediaChangingReceiver(11105): onReceive :
>   ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED
>
> 06-26 17:31:53.528: E/AlarmManagerService(1986):
>   android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=0, 1340721115.533000000

Comment: post the backtrace of the exception from logcat

Answer (score 2):

The `com.android.camera.action.CROP` is part of the internal API so it is not guaranteed to be supported by all Android devices.

You will have to implement your own crop activity if you want it to be supported by all devices. At the very least you should implement some sort of fallback behavior if some device does not support the `Intent`. **PLEASE DON'T FORGET TO DO THIS!!** :)

And by the way, if I recall correctly, the Samsung Galaxy implements its own Media/Gallery app, so that is why it is failing to recognize the Intent.